# Comparing a char to chars in a list in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to compare a `char` to each element in a list of `char`s?

```
char ch;
if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'b' || ch == 'c')
```

Is there some way to just do

```
if(ch is one of {a, b, c})
```

Comment: use `std::find` or try to maintain a string instead of a list of chars

Comment: Look up `strchr()`, if you're dealing with C-style strings.

Comment: `strchr` is indeed a much simpler solution than any of the "modern C++" methods used by the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `std::find`. Assuming `chars` is your character array and you need to find `ch`.

```
if(std::find(std::begin(chars), std::end(chars), ch) != std::end(chars))
```

Answer (score 12):

Why would you write lambdas or use a throwaway string object when you can just:

```
if (strchr("abc", ch))
```

Comment: What if `"abc"` was bound to a string first. `std::string s = "abc"`. Would it be incorrect to use `strchr` here?

Comment: @Dochevsky: `strchr(some_string.c_str(), ch)` would work, but unless you have a string object for other reasons, it would be a waste.  Construction of a `std::string` object is relatively expensive.

Answer (score 6):

Use : [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

With C++11 :

```
std::string str="abc";

if(std::any_of(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), 
    [ch](const char& x){return x==ch; } ))
{

}
```

Or use a functor:

```
struct comp
{
    comp(char x) :ch(x){}
    bool operator()(const char& x) const
    {
        return x == ch;
    }
    char ch;

};
```

And then,

```
if(std::any_of(str.cbegin(), str.cend(),comp(ch) ))
{

}
```

**Edit** : `std::any_of` might not be efficient enough, just for sake of C++'s `<algorithm>` one can try this out too .

Comment: +1, I always forget that it needs to take a predicate, not a value (which is a shame, IMO).

Comment: I prefer this solution over the ones utilizing `std::find` because it more clearly communicates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Does this algorithm use a loop in its implementation?

Comment: @Dochevsky: Yes, of course it does.  The optimizer may or may not be able to unwind it automatically (likely not).

Comment: @Dochevsky It uses `find_if`, so yes

Comment: @BenVoigt. Would that mean comparing each value like originally done is more effective?

Comment: @Dochevsky: In terms of efficiency, best is a lookup-table, then comparison using minimal sets of contiguous ranges (see Doug's answer), then the code in the question and Vlad's which should be equivalent at runtime, then `strchr` as in my answer, then `std::find` or `std::any_of` in a character array, and slowest will be iteration in a throwaway string object.

Comment: Note that some architectures might have slightly difference performance, but I wouldn't expect the above ordering to be wrong by more than one place on any system.

Comment: @BenVoigt And now I feel I shouldn't have posted this :'( I saw `C++` and got crazy with STL "algorithmic way"

Comment: @P0W: In most code, efficiency is less important than readability or maintainability.  And alternate solutions are always welcomed.  I just can't vote for this one because IMO it fails on readability as well as performance.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is searching a string, like this:

```
string abc("abc");
if (abc.find(ch) != string::npos) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, the member `find` is much easier to use (and read) than the generic version from `<algorithm>`.  Can be used with a temporary `string` object, even, as `string("abc").find(ch)` or with user-defined literals, `"abc"str.find(ch)`.  But still very verbose compared to the `<string.h>` way.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're right - I went for `std::string` for mostly "ideological reasons", although functions of the C library are perfectly fine in C++ as well.

Answer (score 4):

(This answer really only applies if you don't want to use C++ std lib constructs.)

In your specific case, you should be able to do:

```
 if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'c')
```

I also have employed fall-through switch for this case:

```
 switch(ch)
 {
     case 'a':
     case 'b':
     case 'c':
     case 'e':
         ...
         break;
 }
```

Some people don't like fall-through switch/case statements, but I think its less error prone than a massive piece of boolean logic and will perform better than using a data structure for this purpose. The compiler is really good with dealing with switch statements.

Comment: this is what I was about to post :)

Comment: This is dependent on the character set being used, though - those characters are not required to be contiguous (unlike the decimal digits, for instance).

Comment: @Paul this will work for ASCII and UTF8. UTF16 would be a wide char.

Comment: @DougT.: Agreed, it would. Something like `if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'm')` would fail with EBCDIC, for instance, though.

Comment: I think EBCDIC is obscure enough that it is okay to pretend it doesn't exist.  In fact, I think it's a safe bet that the assumption `('z' - 'a' == 25)` is more portable than C++ itself.

Comment: It may well be a safe bet, but writing code which doesn't assume it is even safer, and, in this particular case, actually easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use variadic template arguments, which were introduced in C++11, then you can do [something like this](https://gist.github.com/posedge/6851097):

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
inline bool in(const Key& key, const Value& value) {
    return key == value;
}

template <typename Key, typename Value0, typename ...ValueN>
inline bool in(const Key& key, const Value0& value, ValueN &&...args) {
    return (key == value ? true : in(key, std::forward<ValueN>(args)...));
}
```

I use it for strings like this:

```
if (in(some_string, "base", "os", "io", "coroutine", "debug")) ...
```

But other types that support comparison (`char` is one of them) should also work.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just as another option, create a `set` with the characters, and check if it's contained there;

```
std::set<char> mySet = {'a','b','c'};  // C++11 initializer list

if(mySet.find('d') != mySet.end()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of surprised that nobody suggested find_first_of.

```cpp
    char c('e');

// we can check if c is undesirable
    const std::string unwanted("abc");
    bool undesirable = (unwanted.find_first_of(c) != std::string::npos);
 
// OR we can check if c is desirable
    const std::string wanted("def");
    bool desirable = (wanted.find_first_of(c) != std::string::npos); //..or check if it's desirable.
```

I use this (maybe I shouldn't? folks?) for ignoring unwanted characters from a string iterator...

```cpp
/** in and out are string iterators.
  * skip over any undesirable characters by matching 
  * against desirable and looking for npos.
 **/
const std::string ok("!+-./0123456789:^ABFIORmn");
while (ok.find_first_of(*in) == string::npos && in < out) {
    in++;
}
```

A nice benefit of this is that by putting more frequent characters at the front of the string, there's a little bit of saving in time.